# The interpretation of the economic significance in log-level models

Tags: regression-coefficients, logarithm

Hi I have searched for many articles but still confused about the interpretation of the economic significance. Here is the result

Ln(number of Employees)= -2.37 X

Std of X= 0.09
How should I interpret the coeficient -2.37 ? Can I just say one standard diviation (0.09) increase in X will be associated with (2.37*std of X then take exp) 1.23 decrease annual Number of Employees? Thanks